# StarCraft2: How to toggle quickly health bar displaying mode?

Tags: starcraft-2

Here is link how to switch 'health bar' displaying mode:
[How do I have health bars displayed at all times in Starcraft II?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5426/how-to-have-health-bars-displayed-at-all-times-in-starcraft-ii)

But sometime it is useful to switch from "ALWAYS" to "SELECTED". Is it possible to do that quickly without going to menu and clicking 5 buttons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding `ALT` will turn all health bars on if you have them set to "off" or "selected," and will turn all health bars off if you have them set to "on."

I don't think there is a way to use a keystroke to toggle in between "always" and "selected." I think the best you can do is turn them always-on, and use `ALT` if you need to see or select something without health bars getting in the way.

Comment: I play with them on all the time and haven't noticed any issues seeing what I need to see.  Not that I'm some great SC2 player, though :P

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the ALT key displays the unit health for all units on the screen. In that case, perhaps you should change the display to "selected" and then you can just press the ALT button when you want to switch to "always".